# Error on apt-get upgrade and install runit package

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to install [the git-daemon-run package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/git-daemon-run), which has a dependency on the runit package.  But the runit package doesn't upgrade properly.

When I run `apt-get upgrade` to upgrade [the runit package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/runit), the following error occurs:

```
Setting up runit (2.1.1-6.2ubuntu3) ...
start: Unknown job: runsvdir
dpkg: error processing package runit (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I checked the Ubuntu bug database and I found [Bug #406621 on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/406621).  Per the solution there I should fix the location of `runsvdir.conf` changing it from the old `event.d` that upstart used to use to `/etc/init` that upstart now uses. But in (my) Ubuntu 14.04 there is no `event.d` in the first place let alone a `runsvdir.conf` there.

I've tried installing or reconfiguring this package, rather than upgrading, but the same error occurred. It's notable that during the git package installation, this error was occurred for the first time.

```
root@local#dpkg -C
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure  or the configure menu option in dselect:
 runit                system-wide service supervision

root@local#apt-get purge runit
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  runit*
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 419 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Removing runit (2.1.1-6.2ubuntu3) ...
stop: Unknown job: runsvdir
Removing SV inittab entry...
Purging configuration files for runit (2.1.1-6.2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
root@local# apt-get install runit
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fgetty
Suggested packages:
  socklog-run
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fgetty runit
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/134 kB of archives.
After this operation, 550 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up fgetty (0.6-5build1) ...
Setting up runit (2.1.1-6.2ubuntu3) ...
start: Unknown job: runsvdir
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: how did you try to install?

Comment: Pleas don't post the same question on different SO sites http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542330/error-on-apt-get-upgrade-and-install-runit-package

Comment: @Maythux apt-get remove and apt-get install  & dpkg -i
Ok, I delete the post on another SO.

Comment: please write down the full command and the output of each command

Comment: A related question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/630731/ .

Answer (score 0):

runsvdir is the application included by runit to launch the assigned service directory (i.e.: /etc/runit/service/default ). This should be ran independent of upstart/sysvinit/systemd/openrc with runit and runit-init or as a helper service by the runsvdir-start shell script or configuration file for Runit. It works in conjunction with runsv and sv and is not supposed to be classed as unknown.